# How to calculate $\int_{ }^{ }\frac{14x+2}{x^2+4}dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals, transcendental-functions

This problem was given to me as part of a transcendental functions homework:

$$\int_{ }^{ }\frac{14x+2}{x^2+4}dx$$

I believe this problem requires substitution as well as sec-1 but i'm having difficulty piecing it together. Thanks!

Comment: Is it $\frac{14x+2}{x^2+4}$?

Comment: I have corrected that for you @Ben DeRenzi.

Comment: yessir the dx should be inside another set of parenthesis I'll edit the problem to make it more clear.

Comment: Write it as $\int \frac{14x}{x^2 + 4} + \int \frac{2}{x^2 + 4}$. Both should now be standard integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{14x+2}{x^2+4}=\frac{14x}{x^2+4}+\frac{2}{x^2+4}$$
And you can use now these:
$$\int \frac{f'}{f}=\log(f)+C$$
And
$$\int \frac{1}{x^2+1}\mathbb{d}x=\tan^{-1}(x)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

We can split the integral up $\int\frac{14x+2}{x^{2}+4}=7\int\frac{2x}{x^{2}+4}+2\int\frac{1}{x^{2}+2^{2}}$ then we use standard results given in Botond's post above. The first integral is a log substitution and the second is a tan substitution. We get the solution $ln(x^{2}+4)+\frac{1}{2}tan^{-1}\frac{x}{2}+c$